# create class and function in one header file without library

Tags: c++

Hello i want to create my own public c++ tool like auto socket connection. but i have two ways and i want to know which way is better.
way 1 :
insert the functions (with source) inside one header file and other people just include the header file and use the functions... 

**sock.h**

```
#include <iostream>

class sock {

    public:

    bool create();
    bool bind();
    bool listen();
}

inline bool sock::create() { ... }
inline bool sock::bind() { ... }
inline bool sock::listen() { ... }
```

and second way is create a header file and also create static lib (c++)

**sock.h**

```
#include <iostream>

class sock {

    public:

    bool create();
    bool bind();
    bool listen();
}
```

**sock.cpp**

```
#include "sock.h"

bool sock::create() { ... }
bool sock::bind() { ... }
bool sock::listen() { ... }
```

which way is better ? ( i choose the first way myself because it's easy for client to just include one header file and use the functions but in second way client must include the header and also include the lib file. is there any problem for first way?

Comment: compile time might be a problem

Comment: There's no problem. As far as I remember function definitions in header files are by default inline, so if you have long functions you may want to consider the second approach.

Comment: Functions default to inline if defined within the class. Outside of the class (either in the header or implementation file) they need to be marked as inline. The optimizer may also choose to inline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functionally there is no problem. But by keeping the function definitions inside the header, every time the header is imported into a source file, all of the definitions will be compiled again, negatively impacting both compile time and binary size (in certain cases).

Best practice is to define only once, forward declare wherever possible. Keep your abstractions water tight.

Unless you're using template classes, in which case header definitions are generally required.

Comment: Does it really impact binary size ? AFAIK you still only have 1 function definition per binary, regardless of having 1 in each compile unit.

Comment: You're correct, I suppose it depends on how many units are importing the functions, and how they are linked.

Comment: so which way is better at all?

Comment: In terms of reducing compile times, not keeping function definitions in their headers is the better choice.